# JObject JSON Parsing Nested Object

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to parse JSON into an array that is formatted like the following:

```
{
    "company": [
        [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Test Company1"
            },
           {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Test Company2"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

I'm using Newtonsoft JObjects to do this. I have the following code so far, which gets me to the "company" object:

```
JObject joResponse = JObject.Parse(json);
JArray arr = (JArray)joResponse["company"];
```

But there is only one value in the array, it's one single value with the all of the JSON nodes in it:

```
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Test Company1"
        },
       {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Test Company2"
        }
    ]
```

So essentially I need to get to that 2nd level, but the 2nd level inside of "company" isn't named so I'm not sure how to access it.

Comment: Just take it by index - `JArray arr = (JArray)joResponse["company"][0]`

Comment: `company`, for unknown reasons, contains a nested array, you need `arr[0][0]["name"]`, `arr[0][1]["id"]` etc. -- Are you sure this JSON is correct?

Comment: @Fabjan this will return the array value from the company

Comment: @Fabjan `JArray arr = (JArray)joResponse["company"][0]` did the trick, thank you! The JSON comes from an API that we do not own, so I'm not sure why they created it with a nested array so that was I was trying to work around. There should be only ever one "company" array in the nest so using [0] should work perfect.

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like this:

```
JToken arr = joResponse["company"]?.Children().First()[1];
```

Or:

```
JToken arr = joResponse["company"]?[0]?[1];
```

Comment: Why using `.Children` and `First` when we could just use indexer instead: `joResponse["company"][0]` ?

Comment: @Fabjan As I understood, he wants to have the entry with id 2. This Code returns this entry.

With `joResponse["company"][0]`, it will return the whole array, not the 2nd entry from the array.

Comment: So `joResponse["company"][0][1]` would be enough. Don't forget that methods as `.First()` are upcasting `JArray` to `IEnumerable` then call `GetEnumerator` and `Next` this adds unnecessary overhead.

Comment: @Fabjan is correct in that I was mainly just trying to select all the records in the "Company" array so I could loop through them, but the trouble I was having was that company was an array of an array - That's what I meant by "2nd level" - sorry for the confusion there. `joResponse["company"][0]` did the trick and your answer includes that also, just selecting only one of the records.

Answer (score 0):

**The easiest way to do this is to create classes to hold each object type.** This is made more complex by the fact that `company` is actually an array of arrays, for some reason.

```cs
class Root
{
    public List<List<Company>> companies { get; set; }
}

class Company
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Then you simply deserialize into the root object

```cs
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);

var companies = result.companies.SelectMany(c => c).ToList();
```

Comment: This solution worked as well for me, and you are correct in the piece that was complex was because `company` being an array of arrays for some unknown reason in the formatting. I assume classes and lists are better practices than Jarray's arrays in this case?

Comment: Yes, `JArray` and `JObject` are for when the JSON structure is entirely unknown, here you know the structure so you should create classes